# maven fails to recognize jetty is installed

Tags: macos, maven, jetty

fresh meat newbie on GCP / Maven on

- OSX 10.14.3 with Visual Studio Code (latest)
- GCP SpringBoot API with Maven
- other questions on jetty seem to be further along than me.
- the 'flow' below is to reveal steps to get to my question in the title...I think it's important to see how I got to where I am, and if you are so kind to offer help, you would want to know this? ok, here we go...

I downloaded the GCP [getting-started-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java) github example and want to run the bookshelf example.

When I look at the multiple POM files I see that each references a project ID for GCP.

I can't use the same project ID as they are unique, just like GCP bucket names.

So, when I run

> gcloud init

and select or create a configuration and make my own project with a unique project id, does that *automatically override every POM file definition of project ID*? Or do I need to do some maven clean command to change it???

Well... when I RTFM in each folder, it says to

> mvn clean jetty:run-exploded -Dbookshelf.bucket=MY-BUCKET

heck even tried:

> mvn jetty:run

and I get a build failure that says:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups

so... I

> brew install jetty

Then to 'get started' jetty says I have to copy the 'plug in' details into my POM file... which one, as there are several??

But when I installed the VS Code plugin, it already updated all POM files; I still get the "No plugin found for prefix 'jetty'" error

I guess I'll stop with that question:

**how do I get maven to 'know' that jetty is installed and work with it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the shorthand plugin goal `jetty:run-exploded` or `jetty:run` maven is attempting to find the plugin.   This shorthand form will need to resolve the `groupId:artifactId:version:goal` in order to run.

The long-hand form of that would be ...

```
$ mvn org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.15.v20190215:run
```

To fix this, just add the plugin to your `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.4.15.v20190215</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

The above will always use that specific version of jetty-maven-plugin when you use the shorthand syntax.

Alternatively, and with less control over which version to use, is to setup a [pluginGroup in maven's `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups)

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.eclipse.jetty</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  ...
</settings>
```